# why it is not considered as multiple inheritance while all classes extends from Object class first and then also extend other classes

Tags: java

Every class is inherited from Object class and they will also extend some other parent class in inheritance why is it not considered as multiple inheritance.

Comment: Because every class has one and only one parent. In multiple inheritance you have more than one parent. An ancestor is *not* a parent.

Comment: can you please eloborate  the answer

Comment: I'm not sure how much more detail can be added, tbh

Comment: Short answer: in an object hierarchy chain, only the "topmost" class implicitly extends Object - the rest of them don't have to. Look at the object hierarchy for the [Window class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html) for a good example. `Window` extends `Container`, which extends `Component`, which extends `Object`. Only the "topmost" class "directly" extends Object.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca I think that the OP is missing the parent/ancestor distinction... I suspect that they're under the impression that `Object` is the parent of every single object (rather than the ancestor).

Comment: @EJoshuaS-ReinstateMonica possible. If that's the case I'd say the answers in the duplicate you found explain this well enough :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because in Java you can directly inherit from only one parent class. We would consider multiple inheritance if you'd be able to extend from multiple classes but that's not a thing in Java.